# How to Display Time (not static) in python?

Tags: python, datetime

Alright,the problem is i'm trying to build a personal assistant with my amateur skills.
I want to display the time which should be running and not be static.

Comment: My OG Source Code: import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print("Current date and time: ")
print(str(now))

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code (don't merely leave it in a comment).

Answer (score 2):

This is what you wanted ? create a endless loop (Since you didn't mention in what situation the loop will end, I assume it will run infinitely until you manually end it) and print() with end='\r' (replace prev print) and pause and refresh every second

```
import time 
import datetime 

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now() 
    print(f"Current Date and Time: {now}    ", end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
```